# how to run iPhone application from Xcode 4 and ios sdk 4.3 for jailbroken iphone

Tags: iphone

I have developed an iPhone application and would like to test it on my personal iPhone without paying 99$.

I'm using Xcode 4 and ios sdk 4.3 on VMWare snow leopard 10.6.7.

I have followed all steps described in http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398, all points succeeded but with no result i couldn't run my application on real device. The application build succeeded for ios 4.3 device but i couldn't run.

Please could anyone help me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you are another step by step guide: [link](http://cazisoft.com/2008/installing-cracked-ipa-on-the-iphone-step-by-step-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Here are other posts:
Install Installous & Cracked Apps on iPhone, iPod Touch & iPad Without Wifi Access
http://jaxov.com/2011/04/install-installous-cracked-apps-on-iphone-without-wifi-access/

How To Install DEB, IPA Files on iPhone without SSH Access?
http://jaxov.com/2010/08/install-deb-files-iphone-without-ssh-wifi/